# unable to use VTK in windows 10, crash everywhere

Tags: vtk

i have downloaded the vtk from source both the latest version 9.1.0 and the previous version
8.2.0,
configured and generate a project file with no error, built the source in visual studio and it was a success also installed it.

but when i run a simple example as SIMPLE as this one https://kitware.github.io/vtk-examples/site/Cxx/GeometricObjects/CylinderExample/

it crashes with
[image]

I also tried to set it up with QT but i also am getting a crash in QVTKOpenGLWidget.
It looks like whatever version I am installing whether its a stand alone or in QT i ant seem to make VTK run.

I am using and configuring VTK for visual studo 2019.

Answer (score 0):

maybe because the 'DEBUG/RELEASE' building setting? [here](https://gitlab.kitware.com/vtk/vtk/-/issues/18178)

if you use 'DEBUG' to build your code,try change it to 'RELEASE'.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).